# WHich site can provide me the FTP acces for backing UP 150GB data

Tags: backup, rsync

I want keep the backup of myServer  data 150GB online.

so that i can run rsync everyday to keep it updated.

is there any reliable company which can provide the ftp/sftp access and have storage space around 200GB for onlinr backing up.

I don't want to use their software to backup but my linux and rsync

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.s3rsync.com/ provides an rsync layer for Amazon S3.

Comment: Is Amazon S3 available in Australia

Comment: @Mirage, that's something that you can find out yourself easily on the Amazon S3 website

Comment: I tried that theu say its only available for USA . i don't understand whats diff between launcing in diff countries. Can't i ftp from anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Rent a VPS server with a large disk partition. Then you can do what you'd like to it. Burst.net is one of the cheaper ones which I'm currently using.